# Axios body being passed as data

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm new to using Axios and see that to pass something in the body you need to put it in `data`. This means that the data is nested like `req.body.data.value`, where I was hoping to have something like `req.body.value`. Is there a way around that or is that just the axios way?

Comment: [Maybe I'm missing something](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuFlv.png) but where did you get the idea that you needed to pass something using `data`?

Comment: This is just the axios way when submitting POST requests - which is what I gather you are trying to do.

When you make a POST request, axios expects certain things to be be on the request body and data is where it looks for request params.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts I'm seeing it here https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config

Comment: In my opinion, it's just poorly written documentation. [This signature](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config-1) seems to imply that you can provide the `data` object directly after the `url` if you use the `post()` convenience method.

Comment: @BrettEast ya and for PUT and OPTIONS too it seems https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config
They do have a params key but that is different than what my needs are.

Comment: @captDaylight You're right, if you wanted to include any other body data to send, then the `data` key is where you would have to put it. I forgot that `params` had it's own key

Comment: @PatrickRoberts you were right with your comment, feel free to make it the answer and I'll mark it correct.